# No internet after installing openconnect

Tags: firefox, internet, vpn, telegram, openconnect

I'd installed Openconnect to use Cisco VPN on Ubuntu 16.04. I've installed it with this command.

`sudo apt-get install openconnect network-manager-openconnect-gnome`

After that I could connect without any problem. I wanted to use Telegram, because it is banned in Iran. Now Telegram works perfectly, but I have no Internet connection in terminal or in Firefox.

I've used this command:

`ping -c 5 8.8.8.8`

and it seems ok, But when I use this command:

`ping -c 5 www.google.com`

it comes with this:

`ping: unknown host www.google.com`

I'm really confused, how can this happen?

My Telegram works but I can't use Firefox or Chrome!!!